# Which iPhone SDK to download?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, iphone-sdk-3.0

In the developer center there are two different downloads for the SDK, one for Leopard and one for Snow Leopard. Which do I download?

Also do I have to download a separate copy of xcode as well or is it part of the download?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snow Leopard is the version of Mac OSX slated to be released in late 2009, if you do not have Snow Leopard you should use the Leopard version.

- Leopard = Mac OS X Version 10.5.x
- Snow Leopard = Mac OS X Version 10.6.x

(you can find this by clicking on the apple at the top left of the screen, and clicking "about this mac")

Xcode is part of the SDK download.

Comment: Thank you. Will snow leopard be free or have to pay? Also I installed the xcode before. Should delete it and install it with the iphone sdk?

Comment: The Snow Leopard upgrade will be $29. You shouldn't have to delete Xcode before installing the iPhone SDK.

Comment: XCode and the iPhone simulator are free. So, to a point, you can develop an app with no money up front. As soon as you want to test the app on an actual device you'll need to pony up the $99 for the iPhone developer program. This will allow you to create the necessary keys to run and debug your app on the phone. Note that the simulator won't allow you to test things like the GPS, compass, accelerometers and such, and doesn't have the memory or performance characteristics as the phone, so it really will only get you so far.

Comment: Thank you. I start to understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

- For the beginner, and for production-level work: Leopard and SDK 3.0
- For the adventurous developer who likes to live dangerously (or get ahead of the curve on new features): Snow Leopard and SDK 3.1

Both of the SDKs are available on Apple's [iPhone Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/), but you'll have to register (which is free until you want to test on a device or submit an app).

Snow Leopard can only be downloaded by "ADC Premier and Select Members" right now (via the [Mac Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/mac/), as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you. By testing on a device you mean testing on my iphone or apple does a service for your testing with their device? It's free for all tests?

Comment: To test on a device, you'll need to sign up for Apple's $99 iPhone dev program, and buy an iPhone or iPod Touch.  Downloading Xcode and using just the simulator is all free, but it's no substitute for testing on an actual device.

Comment: Thank you both. I thought you could freely upload to your iphone. So by additional pay, you get a program to upload your app to the device?

Comment: Crypto certs.  Apple gives you the keys to sign code that will run on your device.  So pretty similar, yes.

Comment: Thank you. I am very new on iphone dev, so please bare with me.

Comment: Nope, don't download Snow Leopard version if you have Leopard because then when you go to test on your device it will give you a weird obscure error and you won't be able to do it.