# Which version of the iPhone 3.0 SDK should I download?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

In the developer center there are two different downloads:

- iPhone SDK 3.0 (Snow Leopard)
- iPhone SDK 3.0 (Leopard)

I have Mac OS X 1.5.7, which I believe is Leopard. But when I download the one for Leopard it tells me it can't "mount" it. When I download the one for Snow Leopard, it downloads and installs fine... However, once I'm using it XCode with the Snow Leopard version, it can't compile for the device. I'm thinking that might be because I downloaded the Snow Leopard one instead of the Leopard one. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135727/for-iphone-dev-using-the-latest-mac-mini-which-iphone-sdk-to-get

Comment: Yep. I guess this question also has the "mounting failed" problem as well though...

Comment: Yep. Good call. I hadn't seen that other question before you pointed it out. I was just giving a reason as to why I didn't just delete this question once you pointed the other one out...

Comment: your comment didn't sound like "pointing something out" :)

Comment: Sorry, I suppose my high level of stress and frustration must have come across in my comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snow Leopard is the version of Mac OSX slated to be released in late 2009, if you do not have Snow Leopard you should use the Leopard version.

```
* Leopard = Mac OS X Version 10.5.x
* Snow Leopard = Mac OS X Version 10.6.x
```

(you can find this by clicking on the apple at the top left of the screen, and clicking "about this mac")

Try downloading from a different browser. If you downloaded the .dmg and it was corrupted, redownloading in the same browser could very well try to open up the already-corrupted version.

Other options are to try to find a mirror of the file, although I would first try the download in another browser, as it's unlikely the released .dmg is corrupted on Apple's side.

Also, if you are behind some sort of Firewall, it is possible that the download is being blocked. Some companies serve up a generic message, like:

> Access Denied (content_filter_denied)
>
> For assistance, contact your network
>   support team.

Instead of the contents of the webpage or file you are trying to download. It is possible that this message is being downloaded in place of the file, and saved to your computer with the name of the file you are trying to download. (This is actually what the problem ended up being in my case).

Answer (score 3):

You should be downloading the Leopard version. If the *.dmg is unable to mount, it's probably been corrupted. I'd try to find a mirror to download from (or find an alternate download source).

Answer (score 1):

You should download leopard, not snow leopard. Snow won't be out until around september, so you have leopard.

Comment: This is probably true... But why is it I can't mount the file to download it? I can't download the 3.0 or 3.1 versions of the SDK for Leopard, but I can for Snow Leopard just fine... WTH?!??

Comment: IDK.. try Justin Niessner's suggestion.